# Linux: CDBurner XP like software

Tags: linux, software-rec, burning, compact-disc

I'm looking for some CD burning software that's like CDBurner XP or Nero.

- I like how they both show how many bytes are remaining when I burn a data DVD.
- Additionally, CDBurner XP can refresh a directory if I delete or add something under the main folder; this makes it very useful to plan the real filesystem.
- CDBurner XP can also compare the DVD to the files and log any which are different.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

K3B should do what you need, and it's free.  It shows the % remaining, and has more features than most Windows CD burning software.

[Click here for complete feature list](http://k3b.plainblack.com/about)

[image]

Comment: +1 - k3b is such an awesome program . I just wish I didn't have to bring in half of KDE with it when I install it. Great application.

Comment: One thing I don't found in k3b is "Auto Title". That was very good function in Windows softwares.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend K3B. If you have Gnome, you can also use Brasero:
[image]

Comment: Brasero is good, but it cannot show the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Nero is available for Linux:

> http://www.nero.com/enu/linux4.html